# In ios how to programmatically detect when a system prompt is generated on a view?

Tags: xcode, ios8, cllocationmanager

Since system generates an alert for the first time to allow location services, I would like to detect when this ios prompt for location services is generated and not generate my customized prompt when ever system generates. (I would like to generate alert everytime a user is on a view. Trying to avoiding 2 alert views on top of one another).

Comment: Why do you need a custom location services prompt? I don't know of any iOS apps that have their own - doing so may confuse your users.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will only prompt once per app. After the user sets there permissions pref, the OS will not prompt again unless the device (or simulator) is reset.  The OS will show the prompt if `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` returns `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` so, before you do anything with permission, you need to check the status first then you will know if you need to show your custom alert or not.